# What is the return of "tf.train.slice_input_producer()"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I was interested in srgan, and I wanted to run the code with npy type input rather than png type input. However, since there is no function that accepts the npy format(such as "decode_png()"), I was trying to fix the data_loader part. And I had difficulty in "**tf.train.slice_input_producer()**".

In tensorflow, the return of "tf.train.slice_input_producer()" is described as
"A list of tensors, one for each element of tensor_list. If the tensor in tensor_list has shape [N, a, b, .., z], then the corresponding output tensor will have shape [a, b, ..., z]."

But, I do not fully understand this explanation.
For example, if I have a list of 230 image tensors with a height of 100 and a width of 100([230,]), would I return one by one([1,])?

Then, "**read_file()**" returns  its entire contents for one image([100,100])?

```py
with tf.variable_scope('load_image'):
    output = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image_list_LR_tensor, image_list_HR_tensor], shuffle=False, capacity=4096)

    # Reading and decode the images
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader(name='image_reader')
    image_LR = tf.read_file(output[0])
    image_HR = tf.read_file(output[1])

    input_image_LR = tf.image.decode_png(image_LR, channels=3)
    input_image_HR = tf.image.decode_png(image_HR, channels=3)
```